# Entity Framework writing to unknown database

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

I'm fairly new with EF and got myself rather confused about what's going on with my solution.

I'm in the situation where my code appears to be working however the changes aren't being written to the database that I would expect.

I'm using Web Developer 2010 and SQL 2008, code first approach but choosing to make my own changes in the database and manually ensure my classes match correctly.

Things seemed ok until I came across an error where the db hash wasn't what entity framework was expecting, so I looked at modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove(); which wasn't available - it seems that's not around in the later versions. So, I figured if the later versions doesn't do this check, I'll go ahead and remove my reference to EF 4 and put the 4.3 dll in it's place. I think I also ended up deleting and renaming my database. That didn't work, so I followed up on something I found on Scott Gu's blog about naming your dbContext the same as the database, which seemed to help.

However I'm now getting the most bizarre scenario. My code is running, the data is saving, but it's not saving to my database. In fact I'm running a profile trace on the db and it doesn't even seem to be trying to connect. I can change my connection string to something invalid too, but my code will happily run, storing the data #somewhere#

Any ideas what's going on? Might it be using a local database or cache that I'm unaware of? Should I just start my small project again and pretend this never happened? That'd be the professional approach, right?

Comment: if you like to be in control of database, you may use DataBase first approach.

Comment: yes, I think I might start again using DataBase first as it perhaps fits my development approach better. I was trying codefirst though on the theory that it can be readily used on an existing database and wondered how that 'felt'

Comment: the code-first approach made good progress in recent releases, but it may time to get shaped up as complete :)

Comment: Thanks for the steer; I'm getting that sense after only a short time. CodeFirst doesn't seem to make that much sense to me high level - as soon as your code is in production any 2nd, 3rd or subsequent release is using an existing database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest to use Database first approach, if you have your `Database set`, or want to have **maximum control over database**.